# Bamboo recognising JBehave tests

Tags: bamboo, jbehave

I have setup Bamboo to run JBehave tests on a remote agent (with JBehave-web plugin launching test using webdriver), and everything runs fine. Only problem is after the execution is finished Bamboo shows no test executed. I can see the option in Bamboo to select the output of the test results, but it has to be a JUnit xml, and Jbehave reports are only generated in plain text or html.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same situation about a year ago. JBehave "doesn't" integrate with Bamboo out of the box. Although, they have a plugin for Hudson CI.

In my case, such as yours, I resorted in running the tests through the Surefire plugin; the outputs are considered as JUnit tests results and Bamboo can recognize them.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple way to do this. And I'm currently doing this for our build system.

Write a simple parse script that transforms your plain of html report into JUnit compatible results. And add that script as a task in your Bamboo task, then use Junit parser to parse the results. Boo! You're done! Plus, you've got the capability to quarantine!

This is way much faster than writing a plugin for Bamboo, which involves considerable more time to learn/write.

Answer (score 0):

Setup JBehave with Maven.In Bamboo build plan use Maven task to run it. For getting results in Bamboo use JBehave Task for Bamboo. It will convert JBehave scenarios in tests in Bamboo. If scenario names contains JIRA issue ids, it will link them to JIRA issues.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.mdb.plugins.jebehaveforbamboo/server/overview

Sample JBehave as Maven Project 
https://bitbucket.org/vikasborse/jbehavesampleproject/overview
Download or clone this repository on your local machine.
To run navigate to this project in command line and use command:
"mvn integration-test"